# How to merge two separate HTML sections in the mobile version

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want ideas and recommendations of the best ways to handle complex layout of HTML.

I have two separate sections (Left side section and right side section) and they are not related to each other.

But in the mobile screen, the two sections components get merged like the below images:

**Large screen:**
[image]

**Small screen:**

[image]

one of the ideas that I've used before, is the duplication of divs. but I believe there are better than this way.

Please advice.

Comment: Clone RIGHT-A, RIGHT-B, RIGHT-C, RIGHT-D as well as RIGHT-E into left section then show them on mobile screen.

Comment: use CSS media query with flex with order property.

Comment: put ``a``,``b``,``c``,``d`` of left section  into right section and hide it, make it visible only in ``mobile width `` using ``css media query``

Comment: Essentially, there is no simple way to do this in CSS without duplication of content or JS **until** `display:contents` is fully adopted by all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could get this effect using media queries and a grid(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)